# Updating <h:inputText > from outputlabel in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I am new to Jsf Technology and am creating a user registration form. So First I want to display the generated Password in outputlabel and I want the same value that is in Output label to be the same in the inputtext field value for password so that i can save that to the database.  This My sample code

```
<td><h:outputLabel value="userbean:randomPassord()" /></td>
<td><h:inputSecret value="#{userbean.password}"  /></td>

    class userbean{
String password;
public getPassword(){return password;}
public void setPassword(String password){this.password=password;}
public String getRandomPassword()
{
//Code for generating password is here
      return "test";
}
}
```

How Can I achieve this. Can Some please help.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to post some example code from your `userbean` class.

Comment: I'd recommend generating a random password not in the getter but before your view is rendered (depending on the scope of your bean). At the same place you may assign this generated value to a password. By the way assigning generated value to password in getRandomPassword() might help.

Comment: Can provide a sample code on how I can do that